# add character to a string at specific place based on Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, replace

Is there a way to add a character, say `'\t'`, at specific position of the string?

For example:

```
String str = "key1=123 key2=text with spaces key3=foo";
```

I need to replace all spaces before keys with tabs in the key value pair string.

Note that some values may contain spaces.

Comment: Try something out. Create JSFiddle and share it here.

Comment: I tried to split the KV pair based in space but I couldn't as there are space in some of the values. not familiar with the REGEX can you help.

Comment: Follow this [excellent link](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+insert+char+in+string)

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. It sounds like you don't actually know the specific position (that would suggest you know the index already). Instead, it's defined in terms of "every key position" - which you haven't clearly defined. Can your values include `=` signs?

Comment: Most probably you will be succeeded with `String.replaceAll()` method

Comment: yes some values will have = sighs. its log data. I couldn't go with position index based character insertion coz of uncertainty in the values. as the value for the same key will change for each line. each line consist of 50 key values pairs. I consider each line as a string

Comment: string.replaceall() will be a good idea but I need some this like it has replace only the space before the key name. Eg : eventId=34324554\t eventName=new event occurred\tIp=123.345.66.34\t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a look ahead:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" (?=\\w+=)", "\t");
```

or similar, capture the key and put it back:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" (\\w+=)", "\t$1");
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped.